# Why does Handlebars.js take so long to bind after the first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, templatebinding

I have a Handlebars.js template that takes a bunch of data and renders it into a table. The first time it runs, it binds rather quickly and doesn't have any problems. Any subsequent time, however, it takes a long time (even for the same data!) and sometimes crashes the browser. What could be wrong?

In its most generic form, the template looks like this:

```
{{#each this}}
<tr>
    <td>{{data}}</td>
    ...
    <td>{{moredata}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

And the binding logic in JS looks like this (very generic, again):

```
var table = $('#mytable').empty();
$.ajax(url, data).done(function(response) {
    var template = Handlebars.compile(mytemplate);
    table.hide();
    table.html(template(response.data)); //takes a long time after the 1st time
    table.show();
});
```

As I said, the first time this runs, it's very quick to bind. The second and subsequent times, it holds up for a long time at the binding step.

## UPDATE

So while trying to fix this, I pulled the `{{each}}` out of the template and appended each row in a `for` loop in the JS while logging the index. The first run, everything binds super quick and the indexes log in a blur. The second and subsequent runs, each row takes a noticeable amount of time to bind and I can watch each index individually as the rows are being bound....

Comment: Is `response.data` the same on each call to `template()`

Comment: @tkone yes, it is. the data call and response are the same each time

Comment: have you tried isolating this out and just calling `template(response.data)` several times in a row without the DOM manipulation work being done and is it still slow?

Comment: My guess would be that the `table.html()` has to parse the DOM for everything that was there before, remove it and then put the new stuff in which is more intense then just adding it to the DOM. 

I've never used handlebars (though I have one IRL :3) ) but rerunning the template could have lag for similar reasons, mainly cleaning up the template before populating it.

Comment: @Dan [`.html`, when provided a string, dumps the current contents of the DOM element and replaces it with the HTML you've provided it.](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: @Dan i guess i forgot the part where i actually empty out the table... adding that in to my code above

Comment: @tkone good suggestion. i just did that and the response is fast each time without the DOM manipulation

Comment: Just to be clear, in the fixed version, did you end up using .empty().html(...) as mentioned in the comment regarding IE at http://api.jquery.com/html/  ?

Comment: @ledlogic i'm sorry, i'm not sure i understand. yes, i use `.empty()` and then `.html()` when binding data...

Comment: @tkone I'm aware of what `.html` does, my point was how it does it maybe the issue. The internal implementation may be costly after the first run depending on how it's done. This is most likely the case for at least IE as `.empty` is being suggested as a faster way of clearing out what was there making the `.html` call faster. And from what the question poster answered with that seems to be the problem. `.html` most likely has to parse the DOM and re-render the DOM each time it's called.

Answer (score 3):

After much tooling around in the jQuery source and logging of literally everything, I think I've found the culprit(s): `jQuery.append()` and `jQuery.html()` are horrifically slow. By simply taking the literal HTML returned by Handlebars.js and dropping it in the DOM using `.innerHTML`, I was able to immensely speed up the table to near-instant rendering (coupled with `.show()` and `.hide()` to trigger only one repaint and reflow). I think the issue had to be with `jQuery.clone()` or `.cloneNode`, as suggested by the Chrome profiler, but I'm not sure why that was being called in the first place.

Anyways, I'll leave this here in the off chance that it helps someone.

Comment: Upvoted merely for coming back and answering your own question instead of leaving it unanswered.